# Уменьшенная копия изображения

Tags: php

Опыта практически нет, поэтому извиняюсь за может быть глупый вопрос. Проект делаю сам для себя.
Сейчас для каждого товара картинка вводится отдельно большая отдельно маленькая.

```
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>Логотип маленький</b>: </td>
<td>

<?php
if (strlen($filesmall)>0) {
echo "<img src=\"images/catalog/thumb/$filesmall\" border=\"0\"><br>";
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delimage_s\"> Отметьте, чтобы удалить, или выберите новый<br>";
}
?>

<input type="file" name="filesmall" size="40">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td valign="top"><b>Логотип большой</b>: </td>
<td>

<?php 
if (strlen($filebig)>0) { 
echo "<img src=\"images/catalog/$filebig\" border=\"0\"><br>"; 
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delimage_b\"> Отметьте, чтобы удалить, или выберите новый<br>"; 
}
?>

<input type="file" name="filebig" size="40">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>
</tr>
```

как сделать так что бы я вводил только большую картинку, а маленькая создавалась сама, всё маленькие картинки будут одного размера.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы вышенаписаного кода на хостинге должна быть установлена библиотека php - GD . Также дополню код для автоматического ресайза:

```
$size = getimagesize($infile); // Команда создаёт массив с характеристиками исходного изображения.
$iWidth = $size['0'] // Ширина исходного изображения

$iHeight = $size['1'] // Высота исходного изображения

# $resA - Максимальная ширина для горизонтального большого изображения.

# $resB - Максимальная высота для вертикального большого изображения.

# $resC - Максимальный размер для маленьких изображений.

# $BWidth,$BHeight,$SWidth,$SHeight - размеры результирующего изображения

# Вычисляем пропорции изображения

# Если изображение горизонтальное вычисляем пропорции от максимальной ширины.
if($iWidth > $iHeight){
    $Bprop = $resA/$iWidth;
    $BWidth = $resA;
    $BHeight = $iHeight * $Bprop;

    $Sprop = $resC/$iWidth;
    $SWidth = $resC;
    $SHeight = $iHeight * $Sprop;
}
# Если изображение вертикальное вычисляем пропорции от максимальной высоты.
elseif($iHeight > $iWidth){
    $Bprop = $resB/$iHeight;
    $BHeight = $resB;
    $BWidth = $iWidth * $Bprop;

    $Sprop = $resC/$iHeight;
    $SHeight = $resC;
    $SWidth = $iWidth * $Sprop;
}
# а тут если квадратное.
else{
    $BWidth = $iWidth;
    $BHeight = $iHeight;
    $SWidth = $resC;
    $SHeight = $resC;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**$infile** //путь (глобальный/локальный) к файлу, формата JPG
**$outfile** //путь и желаемое название уменьшенного файла, формата JPG 
**$width** //желаемая ширина выходного файла
**$height** //желаемая высота выходного файла  
**$quality** //качество, от 0 до 100. Чем выше значение, тем больше весит файл (75 по умолчанию)

```
function imgresize($infile,$outfile,$width,$height,$quality){

    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($infile);
    $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    imagecopyresampled($img2,$img,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,imagesx($img),imagesy($img));

    imagejpeg($img2,$outfile,$quality);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($img2);
}

imgresize("your_img.jpg","little.jpg",150,200,90); //пример вызова ф-ции
```